# Paper on Excel problem

Tags: correlation, excel

This might be a rather esoteric question, but ....

I once encountered a paper / technical report that showed that Excel (up to some version) was using a numerically non-stable method to compute either the linear correlation coefficient or $R^2$. I cannot find (e.g. google) it anymore as I get this $10^x$ hits on people who discuss CORR or whatever.

Does anybody know what that particular problem was? The authors - as far as I remember - illustrated the problem by some well crafted example data set, for which apparently Excel failed. (Or so my understanding goes.)

Comment: [This one](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwl-HpVJ_5PeUUl5VnlHdzlFbmc/view?usp=sharing)?

Comment: @Antoni Parellada   Thanks for that link and the reference; I already have this rather involved criticism in my portfolio. The piece I am looking for, however, is much more "low-level" than the paper you referenced. The guys there had basically that table of some 10 data pairs and showed that Excel breaks(?)/broke down.

Comment: There is some information on Microsoft's [help page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/828129).

Comment: There's a slew of references at the bottom of [this page](http://www.practicalstats.com/xlsstats/excelstats.html). The link to the Cryer 2001 talk is broken but you can get it from the internet archive [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20071128072706/http://www.cs.uiowa.edu/~jcryer/JSMTalk2001.pdf). $\,$ [I used to have an example of my own I'd show to people to demonstrate how badly broken *VAR* was (because it used the unstable mean-square-minus-squared-mean formula. Microsoft knew it was there and knew it was a problem for about 15 years before they fixed it).]

Comment: @Glen_b: thanks, this is very informing. I found quite a lot of information in the links you provided, but more importantly you mentioning "unstable mean-square-minus-squared-mean formula" is what I was looking for. Do you still have an example data set? I want to show sthg like that in my lectures to warn students from naively believing anything that a computer does .....

Comment: I don't think it's a problem in any recent versions, so unless you have some very old versions of Excel, it would be of little use. I would do it by simulating a longish series of data with a large mean (I was using values above a million) and very small variance (I forget how small, sorry) and then I'd show how the answer changed as you just shifted the data up by small increments (the variance could jump around wildly) -- so I'd make a second column of shifted values and have the shift value being a single cell, which I'd change, and we'd watch how the variance changed. ... ctd

Comment: ctd... (so the mean would go from say a million to a million + 1 to a million +3 and the variance -- which should be constant -- would change by a lot).td ... (so the mean would go from say a million to a million + 1 to a million +3 and the variance -- which should be constant -- would change by a lot).